# Store: Evaluating {order_subtotal} minimum amount in Checkout

Tags: expresso-store

How can we easy check if the {order_subtotal} has a minimum of 50.00 on the first checkout page in Store.
{order_subtotal} holds the amount together with the currency indicator and can therefor not be used for evaluating the amount with a simple if conditional.

Is there another tag with the only the value of the sub_total? Or do we need to manipulate with PHP here?

We want to deactivate the Continue button in the checkout process if the sub_total is not 50.00 (or whatever amount) and show a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `_val` to any price variables to get the unformatted version in any of the store tags (orders, product, checkout, cart) to use in conditionals.

> All price variables are pre-formatted according to your currency formatting settings. If you want the unformatted amount, simply append _val to the variable.

It is mentioned in the docs in passing [here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#product_tag_variables).

So in your checkout template you will want to have something along the lines of:

```
{if order_subtotal_val > 50}
 Your Subtotal is over $50.00 logic
{if:else}
 Lets add some more items to the cart your subtotal isn't $50.00
{/if}
```

Comment: Very good,thanks. A more prominent place in the docs for this information could help too.