# Minimum Order Spend

Tags: shopping-cart

Currently we are having our website built and the CMS is ExpressionEngine. I have requested to condition the site that no orders can be processed unless the order amounts to $50 or more. However, I have been advised that setting up a minimum order spend is difficult. Can someone please confirm if there is plug in or rule that can be applied to have this requirement in the store settings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a fumction within the module but this seems like a solid [logical work-around:](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/34950/166)